# Can i have Multiple ViewModels being held in a ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm

I was wondering what your thoughts are on having a ViewModel containing a collection of other ViewModels.

For example if i have a stock price screen.  In the MainView i want to be able to selct a stock ticker.  When i press the ADD button on the MainView it should display a new stock price in the MainView.

My question is about how the add button should work?

Which of the two options should the Add button on the MainView do:

1) Pass the stock ticker (MSFT) to **StockPriceService**.  The **StockPriceService** will retrive a **StockPrice** object.  I can then pass the **StockPrice** object into a **StockPriceViewModel**.  The **MainViewModel** will contain a collection of **StockPriceViewModel**.

2) pass the stock ticker(MSFT) into the **StockPriceViewModel**.  The **StockPriceViewModel** will be implemented to call the **StockPriceService** and retrive the **StockPrice** object.  The the **StockPrice** object will then be wrapped in the **StockPriceViewModel**.

Thanks,

CA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Add button is part of the MainView then it's events really should be handled by the MainViewModel and access to data for the StockPriceViewModel and thus StockPrice object, by the StockPrice related code.

The way to look at this is that you should still be able to display a StockPriceViewModel with populated data without recourse to any code in any other ViewModels, but in this case it is the MainViewModel that triggers the creation/instantiation of a new StockPriceViewModel etc.

So that would mean go with mostly method 2, say passing an initialisation value to the StockPriceViewModel constructor.